# importing code from another file in vb.net (nesting while running)

Tags: vb.net, object, local

In python you can have

> ```
> execfile(filename.py)
> ```

python will run filename.py and all the variables and functions in filename.py will be locally available inside your current program.
I am wondering if this is possible (in such a simple fashion) in vb.net or not (without importing and adding too many references)?

Comment: If you have the source code, make an instance of the second program.

Comment: There are ways to accomplish something similar involving assemblies and reflection.  It wouldn't necessarily require adding any references, but unless designed well, the resulting code would be fragile and bug-prone.